# What is the difference between summary() and loadings() for princomp() object in R?

Tags: r, pca

Example code:

```
(pc.cr <- princomp(USArrests))  
summary(pc.cr)
loadings(pc.cr)  ## note that blank entries are small but not zero
```

I am getting different outputs from each, and I am not sure I understand what the difference is.

Here is the output:

```
> summary(pc.cr)
Importance of components:
                           Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3       Comp.4
Standard deviation     82.8908472 14.06956001 6.424204055 2.4578367034
Proportion of Variance  0.9655342  0.02781734 0.005799535 0.0008489079
Cumulative Proportion   0.9655342  0.99335156 0.999151092 1.0000000000


> loadings(pc.cr)  ## note that blank entries are small but not zero

...

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00
```

P.S: how can I get access to the table created by summary(pc.cr)?? (I can't seem to find it in str.)

Comment: For the 2nd question, you mean the eigenvectors or the component loadings summary?

Comment: Hi chl - I mean the output from "summary(pc.cr)" - for some reason, I can't find it. (doing something like summary(pc.cr)[[1]] will get me only part of the table)

Comment: Why do you have `# inappropriate` comment in the first line?

Comment: @amoeba -  I honestly don't remember. I removed it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first output is the correct and most useful one. Calling `loadings()` on your object just returns a summary where the SS are always equal to 1, hence the % variance is just the SS loadings divided by the number of variables. It makes sense only when using Factor Analysis (like in `factanal`). I never use `princomp` or its SVD-based alternative (`prcomp`), and I prefer the [FactoMineR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/index.html) or [ade4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ade4/index.html) package which are by far more powerful!

About your second question, the `summary()` function just returns the SD for each component (`pc.cr$sdev` in your case), and the rest of the table seems to be computed afterwards (through the `print` or `show` method, I didn't investigate this in details).

```
> getS3method("summary","princomp")
function (object, loadings = FALSE, cutoff = 0.1, ...)
{
    object$cutoff <- cutoff
    object$print.loadings <- loadings
    class(object) <- "summary.princomp"
    object
}
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

What `princomp()` itself does may be viewed using `getAnywhere("princomp.default")`.

Comment: +1 I also use FactoMineR but I remember that when I tried it's PCA method on a really large dataset, I never got results.

Comment: @gd047 It failed for me too, though it is based on an SVD (might be optimized to handle large data set :)